# Force NSMeasurementFormatter to get value over 1 with NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsNaturalScale optiion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmeasurementformatter, nsmeasurement

If we put the value 100g into a NSUnit and use NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsNaturalScale to get a translated String, the result is 3.52 oz for Imperial system.
The problem is with Metric, the result is 0,1 kg which is the good value but i need to keep 100g. It's for a recipe and and it's more common to keep "g" when the value is below 1 kg.

Tested with meters the problem don't exist, 100m is 100m in metric probably because meter is the base value like kg (and not g).

Is there a way to force it to have a value over 1 instead of 0,xx ?

```
NSUnitMass *g = [NSUnitMass grams];
NSMeasurement *measurementGramm = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:100 unit:g];
NSMeasurementFormatter *formatter = [[NSMeasurementFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setUnitOptions:NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsNaturalScale];
NSLog(@"NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsNaturalScale ---------- %@", [formatter stringFromUnit:g]);
```

Comment: This code in this article is in Swift, but it might give you an idea of how to tackle the problem - https://medium.com/@pwilko/scaling-measurement-in-swift-71f3c1856458

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier, I assume that stored value is based on kg.

```
NSMeasurement *measurement = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:0.1 unit:NSUnitMass.kilograms];
NSLog(@"Measurement value = %@", measurement);
```

`NSLog` result

```
Measurement value = <NSMeasurement: 0x28028ada0> value: 0.100000 unit: kg
```

Here we can see that we have a value of `0.1` and unit in `kg`.

> It's for a recipe and and it's more common to keep "g" when the value is below 1 kg.

We can convert the `unit` if the `value` is below `1`

```
NSMeasurementFormatter *formatter = [[NSMeasurementFormatter alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);

if (measurement.doubleValue < 1.0) {
    NSLog(@"Locale (G) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:[measurement measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitMass.grams]]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);
}
```

`NSLog` result

```
Locale (KG) measurement value = 0,1 kg
Locale (G) measurement value = 0,1 kg
```

The result is still in `kg`, this is caused by `unitOptions`

> By default, if unitOptions is set to the empty set, the formatter will do the following:
>
> - kilocalories may be formatted as "C" instead of "kcal" depending on the locale.
> - kilometersPerHour may be formatted as "miles per hour" for US and UK locales but "kilometers per hour" for other locales.

We just have to change that

```
formatter.unitOptions = NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsProvidedUnit;

if (measurement.doubleValue < 1.0) {
    NSLog(@"Locale (G) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:[measurement measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitMass.grams]]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);
}
```

`NSLog` result

```
Locale (G) measurement value = 100 g
```

Full code

```
NSMeasurement *measurement = [[NSMeasurement alloc] initWithDoubleValue:0.1 unit:NSUnitMass.kilograms];
NSLog(@"Measurement value = %@", measurement);

NSMeasurementFormatter *formatter = [[NSMeasurementFormatter alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);

if (measurement.doubleValue < 1.0) {
    NSLog(@"Locale (G) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:[measurement measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitMass.grams]]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);
}

formatter.unitOptions = NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsProvidedUnit;

if (measurement.doubleValue < 1.0) {
    NSLog(@"Locale (G) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:[measurement measurementByConvertingToUnit:NSUnitMass.grams]]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Locale (KG) measurement value = %@", [formatter stringFromMeasurement:measurement]);
}
```

Comment: The math is fine but i can't imagine how many lines of code i need to use if i must test every value for different unit (g, kg, ml, oz...). The NSMeasurementFormatterUnitOptionsNaturalScale should have a option to get the prefered format since it convert the value in a more natural readable format